# start new activity using intent in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm totally new in android. I'm not sure if I'm asking the right question!

I wanna open a new activity, but I have a problem, when I click to open new activity, I open the same activity in every time.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Tab1Cours extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.recycler_view, container, false);
        ContentAdapter adapter = new ContentAdapter(recyclerView.getContext());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        return recyclerView;

    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView avator;
        public TextView name;
        public TextView description;
        private Context context;



        public ViewHolder(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent) {
            super(inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1cours, parent, false));

            context = itemView.getContext();

            avator = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dis);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    final Intent intent;
                    switch (getAdapterPostion()){
                        case 0:
                            intent =  new Intent(context, Tab1Semester1.class);
                            break;

                        case 1:
                            intent =  new Intent(context, Tab1Semester2.class);

                            break;

                        case 2:
                            intent =  new Intent(context, Tab1Semester3.class);
                            break;

                        case 3:
                            intent =  new Intent(context, Tab1Semester4.class);
                            break;

                        case 4:
                            intent =  new Intent(context, Tab1Semester5E.class);
                            break;

                        case 5:
                            intent =  new Intent(context, Tab1Semester5G.class);
                            break;

                        case 6:
                            intent =  new Intent(context, Tab1Semester6E.class);
                            break;

                        default:
                            intent =  new Intent(context, Tab1Semester6G.class);
                            break;

                    }
                    context.startActivity(intent);

                }
            });
        }

        private int getAdapterPostion() {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public static class ContentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {
        // Set numbers of List in RecyclerView.
        private static final int LENGTH = 8;

        private final String[] mPlaces;
        private final String[] mPlaceDesc;
        private final Drawable[] mPlaceAvators;

        public ContentAdapter(Context context) {
            Resources resources = context.getResources();
            mPlaces = resources.getStringArray(R.array.places);
            mPlaceDesc = resources.getStringArray(R.array.place_desc);
            TypedArray a = resources.obtainTypedArray(R.array.place_avator);
            mPlaceAvators = new Drawable[a.length()];
            for (int i = 0; i < mPlaceAvators.length; i++) {
                mPlaceAvators[i] = a.getDrawable(i);
            }
            a.recycle();
        }
        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), parent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.avator.setImageDrawable(mPlaceAvators[position % mPlaceAvators.length]);
            holder.name.setText(mPlaces[position % mPlaces.length]);
            holder.description.setText(mPlaceDesc[position % mPlaceDesc.length]);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return LENGTH;
        }
    }}
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set onClickListener in your onBindViewHolder method instead of constructor. 
Use position to identify which is the right activity to launch:

`public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
// get clickable view with your holder
// use case switch to launch different activities based on the position of the onBindViewHolder method 
}`

Comment: i'm new in code, i don't know how to do it? please, can you write the code??

Comment: I can't write the code because I'm not in possession of your layout.xml. Assign an id to the container of your layout and assign to it the click listener

Comment: do you mind if i send you my project source code to take a look?

Comment: no problem, use github to share code. Here is my profile: https://github.com/ngallazzi

Comment: please take a look at you email, i share it with you in google drive.